# On an isomorphism of rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, it's claimed in algebraic geometry textbook that $k[v^2, v^3]\cong k[t, u]/(t^2-u^3)$ via $v^2\mapsto u, v^3\mapsto t$. But I can't show it's well-defined, since an integer can have many ways to write as $2i+3j$. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, for instance $20=2\times1+3\times 6$ and $20=2\times7+3\times 2$. So $v^{20}$ should go to $ut^6$ and $u^7t^2$? Luckily that's not a problem, as $ut^6-u^7t^2$ is a multiple of $t^2-u^3$.

Comment: OK, I think I know how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Instead you should try to show that $\phi : k[t,u] \longrightarrow k[v^2,v^3]$ has kernel generated by $(t^2-u^3).$ This map will be surjective, and well defined.The first isomorphism theorem will give you the desired result.

Comment: Indeed I did this, but similar problem arise. It's not easy to show the kernel is of that form.

Comment: Write out some of your work on the kernel in the question block then, and let's see if we can get to the root of the problem.

Comment: I can only show the coefficients of the beginning terms vanish. I want to do induction on 2i+3j on t^iu^j, but seems massy.

Comment: You don't need to worry about using induction. What you should take $\phi$ as described, and ask yourself if you had a polynomial $\phi(p(t,u))=0,$ that is $p(v^2,v^3)=0,$ then what could you say about the kernel of this map? Angina Seng gave you the way to see the answer in their comment on your original post.

Comment: Why do you always say "what could you say..."? That's where I was stuck. If you have an answer, please write it inside above.

Comment: Because asking you the question, rather than telling you exactly what to do helps you learn.

Comment: @Lao-tzu to avoid explicit calculation, you can also note that the ideal $(u^2 - t^3)$ is prime, the kernel is a prime but non-maximal ideal containing it (since image is domain but not field); but the dimension of the ring is just 2.

Comment: @hunter Thanks, that's one way.